# Creating x-y Graph and a circle around a point with specific radius

Tags: tikz-pgf

basically I want to demonstrate an algorithm (LOF) which uses circles that show its k-Nearest Neigbours.

I've created a python script to create Figures for me and someone suggested to me to use LaTeX instead.

This is the graph I want to create:
(Circle has Radius 2 and its origin is (0,0))
[image]

This is what I came up with so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    % help lines
    \draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-0.05,-0.05) grid (5.95,5.95);
    % axis
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (6,0);
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,6);
    
    % points
    \foreach \Point/\PointLabel in {(0,0)/X_j, (0,2)/D, (2,-2)/X_i, (1,1)/X_i, (2,0)/B}
    \draw[fill=black] \Point circle (0.05) node[above right] {$\PointLabel$};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is what I've came up with so far:

[image]

The center of the Picture should be where (0,0) lies and also all the numbers on the x-y Axis are missing. Any way to make it so the origin shifts? So when I use (0,0) it's in the center instead.

I'm very new to LaTeX and after trying it a little bit on my own I figured I might ask here.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: final after this perfect answer:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  For future reference, It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  That way those trying to help can focus on the solution as opposed to setting up the problem test case. This will also serve as a test case and ensure that the solution actually works for you as sometimes the solution is dependent on the pacakges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `scope` to apply a shift. Thus,

```
\begin{scope}[shift={(1,3)}]
    <code at (0,0)>
\end{scope}
```

will shift all code drawn relative to `(0,0)` by `(1,3)`.

The tick marks can be added with a simple `\foreach` loop:

```
\foreach \x in {0,...,6} {
    \node [below, font=\small] at (\x,0) {\x};
    \node [left,  font=\small] at (0,\x) {\x};
}
```

[image]

#### Notes:

- For more complicated graphs you should use `pgfplots`. But since you are starting  out, this should get you going for now.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    % help lines
    \draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (0,0) grid (6,6);
    
    % tick marks
    \foreach \x in {0,...,6} {
        \node [below, font=\small] at (\x,0) {\x};
        \node [left,  font=\small] at (0,\x) {\x};
    }
    
    % axis
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (6.2,0);
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,6.2);
    
    \begin{scope}[shift={(1,3)}]
        \draw [orange, ultra thick, radius=2] circle;
        % points
        \foreach \Point/\PointLabel in {(0,0)/X_j, (0,2)/D, (2,-2)/X_i, (1,1)/X_i, (2,0)/B}
        \draw[fill=black] \Point circle (0.05) node[above right] {$\PointLabel$};
    \end{scope}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a pretty good idea. Any way I can add some numbers to the coordinates?

Comment: @Lisa: Have updated the answer to include the coordinates

Comment: +1 surely. Peraphs it is better to put the orange circle in background. :-)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I shifted it around a little bit and now it perfectly fits my needs!

Comment: Actually, that's a pretty good idea Sebastiano. Any quick ways of doing that?

Comment: @Sebastiano: Excellent idea. Answer updated.  Just drawing the circle first, before placing the nodes puts it in the background.

Comment: I've got another quick question: I've created a line that indicates the radius of the circle but I'm not quite sure how to add a label onto that line:

\draw[thick, red] (1,3) -- (1,-1);

Also, is there an easy way of coloring the node names? :)

I know it's usually one question -> one answer, maybe I should just create a new topic instead then.

Comment: You can try `\draw[thick, red] (1,3) -- (1,-1) node [pos=0.5, red] {$r$};`

Comment: That kinda does the job. I also figured out how to rotate it. Now I just have to find out how to put some offset to it so it's not directly in the line :D Thanks a lot so far

Comment: To move the node slightly you can other node option such as `above`, `below`, `left`, `right`, etc, include a `shift={(x,y)}`, or change the `anchor=south` (assuming it was placed `above) as the node option.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

You need `TikZ`if you want to shift the coordinate labels to the right

```
\documentclass[margin=.5cm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-base,tkz-euclide}
% \usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=6,ymin=0,ymax=6]
  \tkzGrid[very thin,teal]
   \tkzDrawXY
  \begin{scope}[shift={(3,3)}]
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,0){B}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,2){D}
    \tkzDefPoint(1,1){C}
     \tkzDefPoint(2,-2){E}
    \tkzDrawCircle[orange,line width=2pt](A,B)
    \tkzDrawPoints[size=4](A,...,E)
    \tkzLabelPoints(B,D)
    \tkzLabelPoint(A){$X_j$}
    \tkzLabelPoint(C){$X_i$}
    \tkzLabelPoint(E){$X_i$}
  \end{scope}

 \foreach \i in {-3,...,3} {
        \node [below, font=\small] at (\i+3,0) {\i};
        \node [left,  font=\small] at (0,\i+3) {\i};}
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The Code for this is very easy on the eye. Whats the easiest way to shift the coordinate labels to the right?

As in: changing where (0,0) (the origin) is at. Let's say I would like to change it to where the 3 is at right now, both of these labels should be 0. Basically move the x-axis to the right by 3 and move the y axis up by 3.

Comment: @Lisa to get the same figure as yours? Everything is possible and if necessary we can use TikZ!

Comment: Yes exactly! In the other code I just played around with the foreach. I basically would like to shift the origin of the graph.

Comment: @Lisa When you write:  Whats the easiest way to shift the coordinate labels to the right? are you thinking about axis labels?

Comment: Exactly, just the labeling. You can look at the last picture I added into the main question.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I just removed the first 3 lines of your code and basically added the same concept from above